# Is there any way to vlookup in a date range?

Tags: excel, date, range, vlookup, lookup

```
Item no  Unit Cost  Starting Date   Ending Date
A12345    1.00      1/Feb/2016      6/Feb/2017
A12345    2.00      7/Feb/2017      31/Dec/2017
```

If date = 01/Mar/2017, price is 2.00

How can I Vlookup the unit cost within the date range? Is it better to use VBA or direct formula?

Answer (score 0):

If the 4ᵗʰ parameter is omitted, [approximate match](https://support.office.com/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is used instead:

```
= VLOOKUP( --"01/Mar/2017", B2:C3, 2 )
```

meaning that any date from 7/Feb/2017 will return 2.00, and any date before 1/Feb/2016 an #N/A error.

Comment: Hi Slai, thanks for your help. It seems like it's not looking up to the item number. in my report, i've more than 200 items. Is there any ways that i can use? in this case, the item number is unique. if we use VBA, any advices?